# How to Fix HMR Bundle Rebuild not working

Tags: asp.net-core, webpack, angular6, webpack-hmr

I have an angular 6 app running on dotnet core 2.2. The application builds fine, however when I make any changes to the any of the modules, the app breaks.

Looking at the console, I can see that

HMR bundle Rebuilding kicks in
Then after a while I get an error: http://localhost:51228/dist/__webpack_hmr net::ERR_ABORTED 500 (Internal Server Error)

If I then try to navigate to that url, I see a Socket Exception error:

```
SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(string host, int port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

When I rebuild the application and the application starts fine, I am able to access the url http://localhost:51228/dist/__webpack_hmr or any other file within the dist folder, but the moment I make changes, I can no longer.

Comment: Mine you share a application structure and how the webpack file look like ?

Comment: Hi @TonyNgo, thanks for your time. So I had to work back the changes that have occurred on the repo, it turns out that the introduction of pdfJS library https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ broke the HMR functionality. I am however looking through to now find a fix.

Comment: Thanks once more, turns out the version of webpack (2) was not compatible with the pdfJS library, and the changes were not reflected in the packages.json nor packages.lock.json as we do not version control the latter. Anyway updated webpack to version 3 and all working well now. Happy days and thanks once more